# Установка цвета в формате hex

Tags: android

нужно изменить параметр background у ImageButton через .java в формате hex: "#a8a8a8"

Этот код не работает

```
ImageButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton);
ImageButton.setBackgroundTintMode(#a8a8a8);
```

Comment: Фраза "код не работает" должна сопровождаться конкретным текстом ошибки, который выдает компилятор или программа. Добавьте в ваш вопрос больше деталей об ошибке. Отредактрировать вопрос можно, нажав на кнопку "[править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1476333/edit)".

Comment: Документацию к методу почитайте, прежде чем заставлять его что-то делать! Он задаёт не цвет фона, а режим нанесения тонировки на фон. Заранее заготовленные цвета следует определять в ресурсах, а не хардкодить: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Color

Comment: iv.setBackgroundColor( 0xffa8a8a8 );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageButton.setBackgroundTintMode(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"));
```

Comment: привет, странно, но код выделяется красным и естественно не работает

Comment: @En32, обновите ваш вопрос, добавьте [в вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1476333/edit) текст ошибки, "код не работает" -- так сложно угадать, что пошло не так.